# How to examine/edit stack memory contents using radare2 in debug mode?

Tags: disassembly, radare2, stack, dumping, stack-variables

How can i examine/edit stack contents using radare2, just like gdb ?
Is there a way to examine memory using $rbp or $rsp register like below.
x $rbp-10 <--- something like this which can dump from this particular offset.

How do i change the memory contents during debugging ?
example: something like set (address)=0xff

Comment: For examine : we can use x same as gdb.
Still searching for how to write to the memory location while debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To examine in radare2 you can think as 'print values' and you can use:

> px                show hexdump 
>    pxl               display N lines (rows) of hexdump 
>    pxr[j]            show words with references to flags and code (q=quiet)

Example: 
*> px [nBytes] @[address][offset]* 

"Print hex 10 bytes at rbp plus 10"

```
[0x5618eccbf77a]> px 10 @rbp+10
```

*> pxl [nLines] @[address][offset]* 

*> pxr [nBytes] @[address][offset]*

To edit you can think as 'write' use:

> w[1248][+-][n]       increment/decrement byte,word..

Example: 
*> w [str] @[address]* 
"Write \x38\x38 at rbp"

```
[0x5618eccbf77a]> w \x38\x38 @rbp
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo. I tried it .. it worked fine.